# Custom Keyboard Apps (IQKeyboardManager & SwiftKey)

Tags: swift, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

I have a user who has this problem in their IphoneX iOS 13.2, he has no "done" button to accept a comment because seems like he is using SwiftKey app for custom keyboards and in my testing IQKeyboardManager is doing good.

So SwiftKey app has a problem with IQKeyboardManager, the done button of the toolbar is not showing up and either the "dark theme" on the keyboard.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double check this on that instance.

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.overrideKeyboardAppearance = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.keyboardAppearance = .dark
```